# ggplot 2 y-axis with one offset

Tags: r, ggplot2, timeserieschart

I have a couple of timeseries and I'm trying to maximise my page by plotting them in the same figure using ggplot. This is almost exactly what I want:

[image: Sample figure]

(figure from  Spreen et al, 2008. http://dx.doi.org/10.1029/2005JC003384)

I know how to make 2 y-axis using ggplot, but I'm trying to figure out how to fix the different limits and labels on each side.

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput(df)`? So we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

To get the two timeseries in one figure here are two possible ways. `scales = "free"` in the first allows you to vary the limits. The second option has even more flexibility as they are two separate plots treated as one when printed.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Some made up data
data1_df <- tibble(
  facet = 1,
  type = c(rep("ASI", 12), rep("Boot", 12), rep("NASA", 12)),
  date = rep(clock::date_seq(as.Date("2022-01-01"), by = clock::duration_months(1), total_size = 12), 3),
  value = rep(seq(1, 12), 3)
  )

data2_df <- tibble(
  facet = 2,
  type = c(rep("ASI", 12), rep("Boot", 12), rep("NASA", 12)),
  date = rep(clock::date_seq(as.Date("2022-01-01"), by = clock::duration_months(1), total_size = 12), 3),
  value = rep(seq(31, 42), 3)
  )

# Approach 1 - Faceting

bind_rows(data1_df, data2_df) |> 
  ggplot(aes(date, value, colour = type)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~ facet, ncol = 1, scales = "free")
```

[image]

```r
# Approach 2 - Patchwork

library(patchwork)

p1 <- data1_df |> 
  ggplot(aes(date, value, colour = type)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(position = "right")

p2 <- data2_df |> 
  ggplot(aes(date, value, colour = type)) +
  geom_line(show.legend = FALSE)

p1 / p2
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>